# Visual Studio 2015 makes system hang

Tags: freeze, visual-studio-2015

Every time I start `Visual Studio 2015`  in my `Lenovo` laptop it hangs a lot. My configurations are `intel i3 processor` and `1066 MHz 3gb RAM` is there any solution to make it better.

Comment: Run less programs while Visual Studio is running

Comment: it takes almost 2-3 min for loading basic templates .... having same problem with three system of similar configuration @Ramhound

Comment: Give more information please. I have one Lenovo - with a very bad SSHD drive. Things on disc take forever up to a few minutes. A 6 year old Lenovo with SSD makes the start of VS a matter of a few seconds. VS2015 is large - therefore a lot of things get loaded. Then plugins like Resharper can terribly slow down VS. So a lot more about the systems needs to be known. Some of the tips in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-is-vs-2013-very-slow might help.

Comment: it is Model Z560 also 7 year old. But Lenovo G50 1Year old having same problem.